# optimization, lpSolve lp.transport: computational time?

Tags: r, optimization, time, transport, lpsolve

I am trying to run an optimization using lp.transport from the package lpSolve in R, using the generic form

> `lp.transport (cost, "min", row.signs, row.rhs, col.signs, col.rhs)`

The cost matrix is large, 6791 x 15594. The rows correspond to food producers and the columns to consumers, and obviously the sum of all values of row.rhs is equal to that of col.rhs.

The optimization has been running about 12 hours now (using about 30 Mb of memory, in a 64-bits R). Is there any way to estimate the time it will take? Any advice on how to modify the inputs to eventually reduce computational time?

Comment: Because of the integrality constraints, it could take a long time (perhaps days, perhaps millennia or more). If you are fine with an approximate solution, you can remove the integrality constraint (add `integers=NULL`) and round the result.

Comment: in other words, *relax*.

Comment: Thanks, I m trying again with integers=NULL. However that notation seems strange to me (quite new to R). Wouldn´t it be (also?) `all.int = TRUE`

Comment: `all.int` (that would be `all.int = FALSE`) is an argument of `lp`, while `integers` is an argument of `lp.transport`.

Comment: It is still running. I wonder if the issue may be related with the sign of the constrains. I was using "=" for both ‘row.signs‘ and ‘col.signs‘. The constrain is basically that the sum of food tonnes produced (row.rhs) is equal to the demand from the consumers (col.rhs). Would it help if I relieve the constraints to inequalities? How would they look like for cols and columns? ‘<=‘ or ‘>=‘? Thanks

Comment: You can try, but I am not sure that would help (it would help for the first part of the algorithm, finding a feasible solution, if it is not straightforward, but not for the second part, transforming it to an optimal solution). To estimate the time it would take, you can try  to solve smaller problems (100*100, 200*200, 300*300, etc.) and interpolate the time it takes.